# How to run Gephi from NetBeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, gephi

It is [said in manual](https://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Build_Gephi#Open_Gephi_Project), that one should right-click project name and click `Run` in context menu.

Unfortunately, I have `Run` dimmed:

[image]

Why?

`Clean and Build` worked successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since Gephi is a netbeans platform application, it is likely that you need to find the netbeans platform app module (subproject) and Run that one.